# Images getting cut off using Swing

Tags: eclipse, swing, size, java

I am writing a tile based platform game. At the moment I am trying to get 400 tiles to display at once. This is my panel. On the top and left sides everything is working great but on the right and bottom sides the images are cut off by a few pixels. Each image is 32*32. All of `blocks` are initialized. None are null. What is wrong here?

```
public class Pane extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Timer timer;
    boolean setup = false;
    Block[][] blocks;
    Level level;
    public Pane()
    {
        level = new Level();
        level.Generate();
        blocks = level.Parse();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        timer = new Timer(25, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        for(Block[] b : blocks)
        {
            for(Block bx : b)
            {
                // Debug code if(bx.letter.equals("D"))
                // Debug codeSystem.out.println(bx.y*32 +" = "+ bx.x*32);
                g2d.drawImage(bx.bpic, bx.x*32, bx.y*32, this);
            }
        }
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> on the right and bottom sides the images are cut off by a few pixels

If you mean the right and bottom sides of the whole panel (not on the single tiles), than it's probably a LayoutManager related problem. The solution depends on the layout manager you are using for the component your JPanel will be added to.

You could try to specify the minimum/preferred size of your JPanel with:

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.setPreferredSize(...);
pane.setMinimumSize(...);
```

In order to specify its minimum dimension accordingly to the size of the generated image (32 * COL , 32 *  ROW).
Unfortunately the effectiveness of the setPreferredSize call depends on the layout manager of your Pane parent component.

Comment: My pane is fills the window (640*640) The images are cut off at the side and bottom of the window.

Comment: @jbills:is your Pane added directly to the frame or to a container component?

Comment: Directly I think. add(new Pane()); in my frame Constructor

Comment: Yes I used setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640,640));

Comment: Is the window frame large enough to display 640 * 640?

Comment: Should be. I set the frame size to 640*640

Comment: please try to set an higher frame size . If this doesn't work put you jpanel inside another empty JPanel with the layout manager you prefer: JPanel empty = new JPanel(/*specify layout manager*/); Pane panel = new Pane(); empty.add(panel);frame.add(empty);

Answer (score 4):

[JComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) can do that basically and can return very easily something as `MinimumSize` or `PreferredSize`, valid for majority of [standard Swing LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198158/a-question-about-layout-managers/7198523#7198523).